# Using injected DbContext along with DbContext created in Startup.Auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, owin

In Asp.Net MVC, the default template comes with Startup class in Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

According to the comment in this template, an instance of *ApplicationDbContext* is created per request.

In my application, I am using the Repository Pattern and inject *ApplicationDbContext* into the repositories. In my case I am using Ninject,  which can share the same context among multiple repositories if needed.

**Is there any way to use the same injected *ApplicationDbContext* in Startup.Auth**? Not really sure if this is a good idea to change the default template, at the same time we are creating 2 instances of the same context in 1 request...

In my Ninject code, I am binding *ApplicationDbContext* to itself as below:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Not really sure if this a bad practice to bind the context to itself instead of creating an interface? (though it is working fine).

Comment: In my project I get rid of the Owin creation and I delegate all creation of the ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager to my DI container. Don't mix such things otherwise you'lll end up having akward bugs

Comment: @CodeNotFound: thanks, are you able to share how this can be done?

Comment: Why inject into `Startup.Auth` when you can just call `ApplicationDbContext.Create()` to get an instance. Just don't forget to dispose of it when done. Just because you are using DI, does not mean you should inject stuff into every (im)possible place.

Comment: @trailmax: thanks for clarifying this, so your recommendation is that 2 instances of ApplicationDbContext is fine? I don't like the idea of changing the built in template, I just thought since ninject can share the DB context, it might be good idea, and was looking for some input on this.

Comment: @Hooman `ConfigureAuth` is executed on the application startup, possibly even before you have your Ninject container initialised. And it will go out of scope before you'll have any http requests, so no chance to have clashing dbContext instances.

Comment: @Hooman what do you need DB-access for in `ConfigureAuth` anyway?

Comment: @Trailmax: that code is part of the default template that comes with a new MVC project. ApplicationUseManager and ApplicationSignInManager are part of this template and handle authentication/user management... I use them for this purpose.

Comment: @Trailmax: thanks a lot, sounds like my assumption that an extra ApplicationDbContext would be created was not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not really sure if this a bad practice to bind the context to itself
>   instead of creating an interface?

Registering `DbContext` as self and per-request lifetime is pretty normal.

I *personally* like to implement `IDbContext` interface, so that it is more cleaner to mock when I unit test the repositories. So, [my repositories](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Users/UserRepository.cs#L15) depend on abstraction instead of concrete implementation.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
}
```

### [IDbContext](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Data/IDbContext.cs)

```
public interface IDbContext
{
   DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Win, appreciate your answer. Any comment about Startup.Auth?

Comment: I just see that you have registered twice. If you use Ninject, do not register the dependenices inside `Startup.ConfigureAuth`. Instead, place them inside [Ninject bindings](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/commit/80d1f34990ff0860a867cac658cc0b76a7199230#diff-f5b4010a32c69eda3266a5a1969fd1d0), and let Ninject IoC container taking care of Register, Resolve, and Release.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how can I inject IApplicationDbContext into ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve, or create a new question with sample code?

Comment: in MVC, there ts a Startup class, which calls: ConfigureAuth(app); If I want to Inject ApplicationDbContext, I need to inject it into ConfigureAuth and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You cannot inject `ApplicationDbContext` into `ConfigureAuth` without registering first. Do you mean `register`?

Comment: Are you able to explain how can I register it? I have not modified the default template and my ninject binding is as above.